# PHP to check whether or not a file has been uploaded already

Tags: php, javascript

I have a simple php page to allow the user to upload/download files.  My goal is to have a prompt displayed when the user is uploading a document that say either "upload successful" or "file already exists are you sure you want to overwrite".

Here is the code I have so far but it does not work at all.

```
<script>
function alreadyExists()
{
  alert("File already exists. Do you want to Overwrite?");
}
function uploadSuccessful()
{
  alert("File upload successful");
}
</script>

if (file_exists("files/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
  $exists="alreadyExists()";
}
else
{
  $exists="uploadSuccessful()";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    "files/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What message do you see, and what are you doing with `$exists`?

Comment: `$exists="alreadyExists()";` your setting the var $exists to the **string** "alreadyExists()" -- just drop the quotes to run the actual function `alreadyExists()` and the php\js mix is a little wrong to ;-)

Comment: Dear Lord, Calling javascript function using php?

Comment: sounds like you should learn about ajax. you can't call a javascript function from php or vice versa.

Comment: The more research I do do the more I am starting to agree with you sgroves, although the javascript functions appear it doesn't work correctly. I am always keen to learn something new. Khawer Zeshan, sorry we can't all start programming knowing everything. Most of us have to start somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`alreadyExists()` & `uploadSuccessful()` are the `javascript` functions, You cannot call `javscript` function using `php`. This should work like this

```
<?php
if (file_exists("files/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
    echo 'File already exists';
}
else
{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"files/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    echo 'Upload successful';
}
?>
```